# QTreeView - Wait until the drop is complete to perform another action

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyside2, qtreeview

I am using TreeView with a MyTreeModel (which inherits from QAbstractItemModel). This model is fed by a tree structure with nodes as it appears in the documentation.

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#using-drag-and-drop-with-item-views

I have the whole subject of drag and drop between elements of the tree perfectly implemented. As the doc says well, I have reimplemented mimeData, mimeTypes and dropMimeData for it.

Video of it:
https://mega.nz/#!bkoTDQSI!YgVn6jIAPJ86fhexzsGySbhrPwQAK5IwlTTeb5L-sQ4

The problem is that I want to do actions programmatically right after the drop in relation to the item that was dropped.

**I want to expand the item after the drop and I want to select it.** The view on the right depends on the currentIndex.

I have tried everything. Make the selection after:

- rowsInserted
- dataChanged
- currentChanged
- changeEvent
- dropEvent
- eventFilter

Nothing works because if I try to change the selection after those methods, I break Qt inside causing the not terminated drops not to work well. I need to wait for all the signals derived from the drop to finish to execute the select and expand command.

I am desperate, I have watched how TreeWidget behaves and has the same problem as me: when the drop is made the row selected is wrong and the node collapsed.

Comment: My sincere advice would be to rethink your use of a treeview. They are usually hard to program (being one of the more esoteric UI components) and are actually pretty hard to use as well.  Is there another way you can accomplish what you want?  I've implemented quite a few tree view controls and they are rarely as fun as you think they are!  Apologies if this is not the technical reply you hoped for but it's my advice :) Oh, and get some sleep...

Comment: What about using QTimer::singleShot to perform the selection/expand operation (with very short timeout), after e.g. rowsInserted? The operation should be queued after the Qt signal/events about the drop operation

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They have solved it for me in the Qt forums.

I have connected custom signals by adding the parameter `QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection` in `connect`.

Here the solution:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/114716/treeview-wait-until-the-drop-is-complete-to-perform-another-action/3

> 1. I'm not sure why anything should break. Run your model throught the [model test](https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test) to make sure it's implemented 100% according to Qt's
>      expectation
> 2. adding `Qt::QueuedConnection` as the 5th argument of your `connect` ststement should ensure your code gets executed after the move is
>      completed and control is given back to Qt's event loop